# Apache Ignite BinaryObject Bloat

Tags: java, performance, ignite, distributed-caching

I have a custom object which I am converting to BinaryObject (using the BinaryObjectBuilder) before putting it into ignite cache. I calculated the deep size of my custom object and it is about 500 bytes.

But when I calculate the size of BinaryObject, it is a whopping ~8 MB.

Is this expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at `BinaryObjectImpl` class, you will see, that some fields have `@GridDirectTransient` annotations, meaning that these fields are ignored during serialization. These are pretty big objects, like `BinaryContext`, which contains quite a lot of system stuff.

If you want to get approximation of size of a `BinaryObject`, you can cast it to `BinaryObjectImpl` and call `BinaryObjectImpl#array()` method on it. You will get a byte array which is a serialized representation of your object. Size of this array will give you an approximation of the `BinaryObject`'s size.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to something similar. Can't possibly get the type of performance they claim to get by sending ~8MB across the wire. :) Cheers.